# why am i getting an error when assigning pointer to double variable

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working to assign a pointer to a double within C++. When I take the pointer out it runs fine however as soon as I run it with the pointer I get an error saying "cannot convert 'double*' to 'double' in assignment".  I cannot figure out why this is giving me this error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    double ROP, HW, OT,oSal;
    int choice;
    char choice2= (toupper(choice2));
    double * pbsal[2];
    double bsal[2];




   cout<<setprecision (2)<<fixed;

   cout<<"Welcome to the salary calculator!!!"<< endl;
   cout<<""<<endl;
   cout<<"Please enter your hourly rate: "<<endl;
   cin>>ROP;

   while(choice != 3){
   cout<<"Would you like to:"<<endl;
   cout<<"1. Enter the number of hours you worked?"<<endl;
   cout<<"2. Enter the number of overtime hours you worked?"<<endl;
   cout<<"3. Exit the program"<< endl;
   cin>>choice;

   switch(choice){
   case 1:
       cout<<"Please enter the number of hours you worked(excluding 
overtime):"<<endl;
       cin>>HW;
       cout<<"Would you like to see your salary based on the number of 
hours you worked?"<<endl;
       cin>> choice2;
       break;

    case 2:
        cout<<"Please enter the number of hours of overtime you worked:"<< 
endl;
        cin>>OT;

        oSal = (ROP*1.5)*OT;

        cout<<"Your overtime salary is: $"<<oSal<<endl;
        break;



    }
    switch(choice2){
    case 'Y':

        for(int i =0; i<=2; i++){
            bsal[i]=ROP*HW;
            *pbsal[i]= &bsal[i];
        }
        cout<<"Your salary based on the hours you provided is: $" 
<<bsal<<endl;
        cout<<"test"<<*pbsal[0]<<endl;
        cout<<""<<endl;
        break;

    case 'N':
        cout<<"Thank you!"<<endl;
        cout<<""<<endl;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
15:45:42 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Module4 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Module4.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Module4.d" -MT"src/Module4.o" -o "src/Module4.o" "../src/Module4.cpp"
../src/Module4.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../src/Module4.cpp:64:25: error: cannot convert 'double*' to 'double' in assignment
       *pbsal[i]= &bsal[i];
                         ^
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/Module4.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I want to be able to assign the pointer as a double.

Comment: The error is very clear, what are you trying to do with `*pbsal[i]= &bsal[i];`?

Comment: `*pbsal[i]` is dereferenced pointer already. The type of `*pbsal[i]` is `double`, not `double*`

Comment: Your next problem is that your arrays both have a size of 2, the valid indices are [0..1]. The `for` loop will try to access index 2 (outside of both arrays).

Comment: It's strange why you even need to use pointers for a program like this.  It's like you're trying your best to shoehorn pointer usage into a program that frankly doesn't require it.

Comment: You have to do upcase after you get the value not when defining it I.e do upcase after cin>> choice2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers in C++ are a little bit different than their C counterpart.
It should be invoked using the keyword `new` for efficient memory management.
        `double *pbsal = new double[2];`

Now `pbsal[0]` and `pbsal[1]` are just double values. And the loop should be `i<2`not `i<=2`.

```
bsal[i]   = ROP*HW;
pbsal[i]  = bsal[i];
```